# Unable to locate package install

Tags: package-management

```
anon@mous:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential git libpthread-stubs0-dev libpcap-dev qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils cpu-checker cmake install libelf-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package install
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are seeing this error is because you are trying to install a package called "install" (next to cmake and libelf-dev). This looks like a simple typo. Just remove it and it should be fixed, because "install" is not a package.